# From git repository how do I know dependencies versions using in spring boot?

Tags: spring-boot

I know I can open Spring Boot project official page, get to "Learn" tab, select proper version of framework, click "Reference Doc > Dependency versions" and see all the dependencies and their versions.

But I'd like to know how to achieve the same goal, using Spring Boot's git repo. I found build.gradle file [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/3.1.x/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-dependencies/build.gradle) but I'm not sure that it's what I need. For example, I can't find spring-security-core, spring-web, etc there.

So, if I have pom like this:

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>3.2.0-M1</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>

...

<dependencies>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
```

how can I find, what exactly dependencies (and their versions) are contained in spring-boot-starter-security, spring-boot-starter-web ?

Comment: You will have to traverse thru the Pom of the required library

Comment: Since you mentioned `pom`, you could do `mvn dependency:tree` to list dependencies.

Comment: No, that's not what I meant. Forget about that pom, it was just to show how I got boot-pack names, like spring-boot-starter-web. I go to https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/main/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-starters/spring-boot-starter-web/build.gradle and see that spring-boot-starter-web consist of 4 deps, one of them is spring-web. In documentation I see it is 6.0.11. How can I found this version in git? Here https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/3.1.x/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-dependencies/build.gradle is no spring web at all.